# How to push a string into a new array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, push, tally

I want to search for substrings in a given string. Each time the substring is included within the entered string I append it to an array. Ultimately I want to `tally` that array to get a count of how many times each substring appears.

The problem is that the substring from the dictionary in my code is only added once to `new_array`.

For example:

```
dictionary = ["below", "down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part","partner","sit"]

substrings("go going", dictionary)
```

Should output:

```
{"go"=>2, "going"=>1, "i"=>1}
```

but I get

```
{"go"=>1, "going"=>1, "i"=>1}
```

This is my code:

```
def substrings(word, array) 

  new_array = []

  array.each do |index| 

    if word.downcase.include? (index)

      new_array << index

    end
  end

  puts new_array.tally

end

 dictionary = ["below", "down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part","partner","sit"]

 substrings("go going", dictionary)
```

Comment: Tip: For long lists of individual words use `%w[ a b c ... ]` which gives you the same result without all the extra quoting and commas.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how large your dictionary is.

You can just map all the elements with their occurrence count when the substring exists in the word.

```
dictionary.map {|w| [w,word.scan(w).size] if word.include?(w)}.compact.to_h
```

Comment: I like it better than mine. "Elegant!"

Comment: @theTinMan thank you and honestly if you look at my edits my original was similar but worse than yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-scan) to count of how many times each substring appears.

```
def substrings(word, array)
  output = {}
  array.each do |index|
     count_substring_appears = word.scan(index).size
     if count_substring_appears > 0
       output[index] = count_substring_appears
     end
  end

  output
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the words "go", "going" and "i" from your dictionary are substrings of your phrase. Each of these words occurs only once in the dictionary. 
So `new_array` contains `["go", "going", "i"]` which exactly `{"go"=>1, "going"=>1, "i"=>1}`.

I assume you expected `go` to be twice because it is twice in your phrase. In this case you can change your method to

```
def substrings(word, array) 
  new_array = []
  array.each do |index| 
    word.scan(/#{index}/).each { new_array << index }
  end
  puts new_array.tally
end
```

`word.scan(/#{index}/)` returns each occurrence of substring in your phrase.

Comment: The solution by @byakugie is even cleaner

Comment: It is cleaner, but I find myself liking yours. I am just learning ruby and  yours is easiest for me to digest at this moment. Thanks!

Comment: @Maniaci I'm glad if you find it helpful. I wanted to replace as minimum as possible, just to highlight the issue in the original method.

Answer (score 0):

You must count the number of times a string appears in index, so use `scan`:

```
def substrings(word, array) 

  hash = {}

  array.each do |index| 
    if word.downcase.include? (index)
      new_hash = {index => word.scan(/#{index}/).length}; 
      hash.merge!(new_hash) 
    end
  end

  puts hash 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If it my understanding that we are given an array `dictionary` of words containing no whitespace, and a string `str`, and are to construct a hash whose keys are elements of `dictionary` and whose values equal the number of non-overlapping<sup>1</sup> substrings of `str` for which the key is a substring. The hash returned should exclude keys having values of zero.

This answer addresses the situation where, in:

```
substrings(str, dictionary)
```

`dictionary` is large, `str` is not overly-large (the meaning of which I elaborate later) and efficiency is important.

We begin by defining a helper method, whose purpose will become clear.

```
def substr_counts(str)
  str.split.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word,h|
    (1..word.size).each do |sub_len|
      (0..word.size-sub_len).each do |start_idx|
        h[word[start_idx,sub_len]] += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For the example given in the question,

```
substr_counts("go going")
  #=> {"g"=>3, "o"=>2, "go"=>2, "i"=>1, "n"=>1, "oi"=>1, "in"=>1, "ng"=>1,
  #    "goi"=>1, "oin"=>1, "ing"=>1, "goin"=>1, "oing"=>1, "going"=>1}
```

As seen, this method breaks `str` into words, computes each substring of each word and returns a hash whose keys are the substrings and whose values are the total numbers of non-overlapping substrings in all words that contain that substring.

The desired hash can now be constructed quickly.

```
def cover_count(str, dictionary)
  h = substr_counts(str)
  dictionary.each_with_object({}) do |word,g|
    g[word] = h[word] if h.key?(word)
  end
end
```

```
dictionary = ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", 
              "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]
```

```
cover_count("go going", dictionary)
  #=> {"go"=>2, "going"=>1, "i"=>1}
```

Another example:

```
str = "lowner partnership lownliest"
cover_count(str, dictionary)
  #=> {"i"=>2, "low"=>2, "own"=>2, "part"=>1, "partner"=>1}
```

Here,

```
substr_counts(str)
  #=> {"l"=>3, "o"=>2, "w"=>2, "n"=>3, "e"=>3, "r"=>3, "lo"=>2,
  #    ...
  #    "wnliest"=>1, "lownlies"=>1, "ownliest"=>1, "lownliest"=>1} 
substr_counts(str).size
  #=> 109
```

There is an obvious trade-off here. If `str` is long, and especially if it contains long words<sup>2</sup>, it will take too long to build `h` to justify the savings of not having to determine, for each word in `dictionary`, if that word is contained in each word of `str`. If, however, it's worth it to construct `h`, the overall time savings could be substantial.

<sup>1. By "non-overlapping" I mean that if `str` equals `'bobobo'` it contains one, not two, substrings `'bobo'`.</sup>

2. `substr_counts("antidisestablishmentarianism").size #=> 385`, not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-product) after splitting of the word, so you can use [Enumerable#Tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) as you want:

```
word = "go going"
word.split.product(dictionary).select { |a, b| a.include? b }.map(&:last).tally

#=> {"go"=>2, "going"=>1, "i"=>1}
```

It doesn't output the same when `word = "gogoing"`, since it is split in one element array. So, I can't say if this is the behaviour you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with this:

```
dictionary = %w[down go going it i]
target = 'go going'

dictionary.flat_map { |w|
  target.scan(Regexp.new(w, Regexp::IGNORECASE))
}.reject(&:empty?).tally
# => {"go"=>2, "going"=>1, "i"=>1}
```